# sed delete between lines with tree lines

Tags: bash, tomcat, sed

I have several tomcat servers where I want to manage dynamically the context.xml file via some bash scripts and I want to delete resources by using `sed`. I know how do it but the file is formatted as shown below across several servers for sake of readability I suppose and I can't identify the resource to delete just with this:

`sed '/PATTERN-1/,/PATTERN-2/d' context.xml`

But on pattern-1 I need to get the second line to substitute part of name attribute as a bash script variable. And I tried several ways as escaping \s or \n

```
<Context>
  ...
  <Resource 
        name="jdbc/EmployeeDB" auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        description="Employees Database for HR Applications"
  />
  <Resource 
        name="jdbc/SportDB" auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        description="Sport Database for HR Applications"
  />
  <Resource 
        name="jdbc/BackupDB" auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        description="Backup Database for HR Applications"
  />
  ...
</Context>
```

Comment: I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up doing like this

```
cat context.xml | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/<Resource\n/<Resource\ /g;s/ \+/ /gp' | sed -i '/<Resource\ name=\"jdbc\/$2\"/,/\/>/d'
```

The first `sed` turns

```
<Resource
       name="jdbc/example"
       ...
/>
```

into

```
<Resource name="jdbc/example"
       ...
/>
```

with that i can delete between lines with the second `sed` because i have the "identifier"

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you could try the following:

```
sed -ri '/<Resource/,/\/>/ {/name=.*$/d}' filename
```

With -r to allow regular expressions to be interpreted and -i to amend the file directly, you would first isolate the data between  and /> and then delete the lines beginning with name="

Comment: I want to delete the section, not edit. I also already have the script to add new resources. The section begins with `<Resource` and ends with `/>`

If I delete with the first and the last, all resources will be deleted. If I start with `name="database"` the Resource opening tag won't be deleted. It's like delete everything between line 1+2 to 10

Comment: I've amended to delete as opposed to amend

Comment: I guess I haven't explained myself clearly. Nonetheless I got it working. You can check my auto answer.

I just tried to chain the two sed but without success.